# Is it possible that I can claim portals created by me

Tags: ingress

I'm new to ingress and I've a doubt about portal claiming. Is it possible that I can claim portals created by me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once the portal is approved, yes you can hack and even deploy resonators (I believe this is what you mean by "claim") on the portal you have created. It becomes a portal for everyone to see and it will have a "created by [you name]" from then on.

Comment: I belive the first person to deploy a resonator on a neutralized portal will get a temporary (untill neutralized again) 'claim' on it. I forget what this claim was called, tough. It was related to one of the stats counting the longest uninterupted claim.

Comment: @DJPirtu are you talking about the Guardian badge (control a portal for consecutive days)? Yes the first person to control the portal will have a claim I guess if that's what is being referred to.

Comment: @DJPirtu The term your were looking for is **capture**.